# I cant find the solution of these 2 equations with matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-system

$2(x)^2 + (x - y)^3 - 2= 0$

$y - (x - y)^3 + 10 = 0$

I tried to solve these equations by using matlab fsolve command.

Then matlab found no solution.

Can someone solve please?

Comment: So if mathlab found no solutions, what makes you think that there are solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plug in the value of $(x-y)^3$ from the second equation into the first. You will then see that all solutions lie on the parabola:
$$y = -8 - 2x^2$$
Now plug $y$ into the second equation to get a sixth order polynomial, and see if you can get the numerical solutions for that.

For reference, it [appears](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-8+-+2x%5E2+-+%28x%2B8%2B2x%5E2%29%5E3%2B10+%3D%3D+0) there are *no* real solutions.

Comment: i put y = - 8 - 2(x)^2 on the second equation but it gave me no solution again.

Comment: but u use wrong equation is it effects the answer can u try it again with y = -8 -(x)^2.

Comment: @Tuğkan - corrected.